# Windows 10 PIN Sign-in: Your credential could not be verified

Tags: windows-10

I've been using my Windows 10 PIN login for a long time, it recently stopped working and throwing an error: Your credential could not be verified, I'm pretty sure my PIN is correct as I've reset my PIN a couple of time.

Comment: See this article : [PIN sign-in issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026196/windows-pin-sign-in-issues).

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue before, and most of people can fix the issue by the following steps.
1. Disable **Microsoft Hello**  in **Start->Settings->Accounts->Sign-in option** or in local group policy
2. Then restart the machine
3. Log on with local admin account
4. Re-enable the Windows Hello feature
5. Configure the Pin as you need

Hope it can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem.  Although my Microsoft password worked, the Windows PIN did not.  I solved this by removing the PIN sign-in option, then putting it back and creating a new PIN.  I believe the reason this happened is because I had changed my Microsoft password some time in the past and hadn't logged in on this computer with the new password for a while.